# Render image in UI created by r shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am using R to generate an image (png file). How do I use shiny to render it to the ui?

```
source("#rasterBasePlot.R")
    
output$spatialMap <- renderImage ({
    filename <- PNGFileName
    
    # Return a list containing the filename
    list(src = filename)
 }, deleteFile = TRUE)
```

Comment: `plotOutput("spatialMap")` in the UI maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a `www` folder inside your app folder and put the images you want to display there. After that something like the following should be sufficent:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$img(
    src = "/myimage.png", width = 100
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you want to use folders other than `www` you can use `addResourcePath` to add  resources to Shiny's web server. Please see [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.4.0/resourcePaths.html).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. The issue I'm having currently is that it's not uploading the png until after I have reloaded the shiny app.

Comment: You could place `tags$img` in `renderUI` and re-render once the image is available.