# How to source a locally stored image for embedding into a table cell in R Shiny?

Tags: html, r, image, shiny

The below code does a terrific job of rendering a web-sourced image in a cell of the `rhandsontable`. However, I'd like swap that image with a jpg image I have stored on my computer. I've tried modifying the below `as.character(img(src = "..."))` to reflect the local directory and filename, with no luck.

Any suggestions for a straightforward way to do this?

I searched for solutions, for example, [Display locally-stored image in R Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63838001/display-locally-stored-image-in-r-shiny), but they look rather involved given what I thought is the simplicity of what I'm trying to do. Certainly accessing your local drive is easier than reaching out to the Web via API.

Here's the painfully simple image I want to upload (shrunken of course):

[image]

Code:

```
library(magrittr)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

DF = data.frame(
  Col_1 = c("Row 1"), 
  Col_Help = c(
    as.character(img(
      src = "https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/python-logo.png", 
      title = "My first help text", 
      style = "width: 50px;")
      )
  ),
  text = c("Row 1 does xxx"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

ui <- fluidPage(br(),rHandsontableOutput('my_table'))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$my_table <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable::rhandsontable(
      DF,
      allowedTags = "<em><b><strong><a><big><img>"
    ) %>%
      hot_cols(colWidths = c(200, 80)) %>%
      hot_col(1:2, renderer = htmlwidgets::JS("safeHtmlRenderer")) %>%
      hot_cols(colWidths = ifelse(names(DF) != "text", 100, 0.1))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your file, say `question_mark.jpg` in the `www` folder of your shiny app, and then adjust your `DF` definition as below:

```
DF = data.frame(
  Col_1 = c("Row 1"), 
  Col_Help = c(
    as.character(img(
      src = "question_mark.jpg", 
      title = "My first help text", 
      style = "width: 50px;")
      )
  ),
  text = c("Row 1 does xxx"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Output:

[image: shiny_app_running_with_pic_in_cell]

Comment: Hi langtang, how do I find my www folder?

Comment: @Village.Idyot you'll [need to create it](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.4.0/resourcePaths.html). Please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68933400/render-image-in-ui-created-by-r-shiny/68934057#68934057)

Comment: I tried that. I created a www subfolder, containing the image, in the directory where I have the App saved. Still doesn't work. That folder where I have the App saved has many other Apps, for my Stack Overflow questions. Does each App need its own folder? I must be doing something very basic very wrong.

Comment: Yes, usually each app has its own folder containing e.g. an app.R file and a www folder if needed. You can use RStudio's file dialog to create a new app and maybe a corresponding RStudio project.

Comment: Actually I solved something by doing a bit more research!! FINALLY! This link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70162920/how-do-you-use-addresourcepath-in-r-shiny, explains how to use addResourcePath() to map images on a local directory, and it worked! It has a very detailed explanation and I just followed it step-by-step